# Laravel : How to delete Database Notification row by data->postid

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

I have followed this link to create database notification in my laravel blog app , when one user likes other user's post

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#database-notifications

my application successfully able to create database notification as follow

**table : notifications**

> id | type | notifiable_id | notifiable_type | data | read_at |
>     created_at |    updated_at

```
id = 0b2a7fdf-eea4-4982-a86d-e874bb4f28ef

type = App\Notifications\PostLiked

notifiable_id= 48 

data = { "event":"LIKE",
         "postid":17,
         "sender":{
                   "id":50,
                   "name":"Developer",
                  }
       }

read_at = NULL

created_at = 2018-04-07 12:46:42

updated_at = 2018-04-07 12:46:42
```

now i want to delete database notification row by data->postid

I have tried below query  :

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->where('type','App\Notifications\PostLiked')
    ->where('data->postid',17)
    ->first();
```

got error :

> QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '>'$."postid"' = 17) limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select * from
>   notifications where (type = App\Notifications\PostLiked
>   and data->'$."postid"' = 17) limit 1)

I have also tried below query :

> $result=DB::table('notifications')->whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(data,
>   '$.postid') = ?", [17]);

```
{
connection: { },
grammar: { },
processor: { },
bindings: {
select: [ ],
join: [ ],
where: [
17
],
having: [ ],
order: [ ],
union: [ ]
},
aggregate: null,
columns: null,
distinct: false,
from: "notifications",
joins: null,
wheres: [
{
type: "raw",
sql: "JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.postid') = ?",
boolean: "and"
}
],
groups: null,
havings: null,
orders: null,
limit: null,
offset: null,
unions: null,
unionLimit: null,
unionOffset: null,
unionOrders: null,
lock: null,
operators: [
"=",
"<",
">",
"<=",
">=",
"<>",
"!=",
"<=>",
"like",
"like binary",
"not like",
"between",
"ilike",
"&",
"|",
"^",
"<<",
">>",
"rlike",
"regexp",
"not regexp",
"~",
"~*",
"!~",
"!~*",
"similar to",
"not similar to",
"not ilike",
"~~*",
"!~~*"
],
useWritePdo: false
}
```

please suggest me correct query to get row and delete row by json (data.key) in notifications table

Comment: The syntax looks correct. What results do you get if you did a select with the same params?

Comment: I got error in query

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is `data` a `JSON` column?

Comment: yes , data is json column

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir , Question updated , please see the error

Comment: You can try `->where('data', 'like', '%"postid":17%')`

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB doesn't support this notation for querying JSON columns.

You can use raw SQL:

```
->whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.postid') = ?", [17])
```

Or install this package: https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb

Comment: I have tried your answer but not getting database result , instead i got something different , i updated question please see .

Comment: You still have to call `->first()`/`->get()`/`->delete()` at the end.

Comment: The one with `near '>'$."postid"' = 17`?

Comment: `DB::table('notifications')->where('type','App\Notifications\PostLiked')->whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.postid') = ?", [17])->first();` gives you same the error?

Comment: yes . i have tried your query with first() , get() but it gives same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168566/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-saurabh-mistry).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. You can use this query:

```
->where('data', 'like', '%\"postid\":17%' )->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->where('type','App\Notifications\PostLiked')
    ->where('data->postid',17)
    ->first();
```

I guess the bug here is **where('data->postid', 17)**. View **where('name_column_in_table', 'value');**
You can not have a field name in the table **data->posts**

Answer (score 0):

**Yes You can delete**

**1. First you need to send postid in notifications table data column like**

```
   public function toArray($notifiable){
           return [
          'postid'=>$this->postid,
     ];
   }
```

**2. Now see your notifications table you will see**

```
{"postid":post_id_value_here}
```

**2. Apply bellow query from where you want to delete**

```
DB::table('notifications')->where('data->postid', $id)->delete();
```

Don't forget **use DB** at your controller