# how to delete from table Notifications by data in column “ticket_id” in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have create database notification in my laravel app,
but how to delete row from it.

**table : notifications**

id | type | notifiable_id | notifiable_type | data | read_at | created_at | updated_at

```
id = 6f4ec6c2-ac98-4c35-99fe-2eb0559b2aed
type = App\Notifications\NewTicket

notifiable_id= 3 

notifiable_type= App\User

data = {"user_name":"admin","ticket_title":"How to ...","ticket_id":7}

read_at = NULL

created_at = 2019-04-20 

updated_at = 2019-04-20
```

I try

```
DB::table('notifications')

   ->where('data->ticket_id',$id)->get()->first()->delete();
```

Not deleting,

then try

```
 DB::table('notifications')    
 ->whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.ticket_id') = ?", $id)->get()->first()->delete();
```

Not deleting,

How to delete the above row by ticket_id

any help wiill appreciated.

Comment: DB::table('notifications')->where('ticket_id', $id)->delete();

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
->whereJsonContains('data', ['ticket_id' => $id])->first()->delete();
```

Comment: @HimaHima; for delete, you can try this trick:
`->whereJsonContains('data', ['ticket_id' => 'id'])->first()->delete();`

Comment: Thank you, but not working and not give me any error just don't delete ->whereJsonContains('data', ['ticket_id' => 'id'])->get()->first()->delete();

Comment: @HimaHima; dont use get()

Comment: yes, I used your query but not working, I know you, and I know the problem in my app, your query is very good my app have the problem

Comment: @HimaHima I have the same db structure, and I tried this query and it works well, if it is helpful, mark it accepted so that other readers can get help. Thank you

Comment: yeah 'id' is just for example, it will be dynamic, like if your id is saved in $id, then pass $id

Comment: `->whereJsonContains('data', ['ticket_id' => $id])->first()->delete();`

Comment: public function deleteTickets($id){
        $ticket = Tickets::find($id);
        $files = Files::where('ticket_id', $ticket->id)->get();
        foreach ($files as $file){
            Storage::delete($file->name);
        }
        Files::where('ticket_id', $ticket->id)->delete();
        Replies::where('ticket_id', $ticket->id)->delete();

       Tickets::find($id)->get()->first()->delete();
        return 'success';
    }

Comment: where is your `notifications` table and `data` column

Comment: if I used the above query the ticket deleted succesfuly from table(tickets) but I need to delete it from the notifications table also by ticket_id, I know you will understand me

Comment: public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'department_id' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required|min:10|max:300',
            'description' => 'required|min:15|max:10000'
        ]);
        $ticket = new Tickets();
        $ticket->department_id = $request->department_id;
        $ticket->user_id = Auth::id();
        $ticket->token_no = rand(1000, 10000);
        $ticket->subject = $request->subject;
        $ticket->description = $request->description;
        $ticket->status = 'open';
        $ticket->save();

Comment: if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
            $files = new Files();
            $files->name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $files->user_id = (Auth::user()) ? Auth::id() : null;
            $files->ticket_id =  $ticket->id;
            $files->reply_id =  0;
            $files->save();
            Storage::putFileAs('', $request->file, $request->file->getClientOriginalName());
        }

Comment: $title = $request->subject;
        $ticket_id = $ticket->id;
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $users = User::all();
        foreach ($users as $user){
            if($user->hasRole('admin')){
                $user->notify(new NewTicket($title, $user_name, $ticket_id));
            }
        }
      
        return redirect::to('tickets');
    }

Comment: you need to delete `notification`'s row which have 'ticket_id. Right?

Comment: use this
`DB::table('notifications')->whereJsonContains("data", ["ticket_id" => $id])->delete();`

Comment: Here $id is your ticket_id which you wanna delete

Comment: that's the same from my problem,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716591/laravel-how-to-delete-database-notification-row-by-data-postid

Comment: if you find it helpful, upvote it or accept the answer

Comment: Thank you pro for your trying helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the row as following

```
DB::table('notifications')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: thanks you, but didn't work :( I need to delete by ticket_id in column Data

Comment: @HimaHima which one is primary key id OR notifiable_id ?

Comment: the id in the table notifications not the same for ticket_id, notifications table:  id | type | notifiable_id | notifiable_type | data | read_at | created_at | updated_at

Comment: as i can see in your table structure there is no column with the name ticket_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this for deleting by json field:

```
    DB::table('notifications')
      ->where('data->ticket_id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: Thank you, but not working and not give me any error just don't delete

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem i solved this from

```
$notification = DB::table('notifications')::get();
foreach($notification as $notify) {
  if(json_decode($notify->data)->ticket_id== $id) {
      $notify->delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).